# (Look forward / eagerly wait / cannot wait) + noun

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

Could someone please tell me if all the sentences below mean the same in each set and if there is any unnatural one between them?

> 1.1. I **look forward** to Christmas every year. 
>   1.2. I **eagerly wait** for Christmas every year. 
>   1.3. I **cannot wait** for Christmas every year.

Or

> Suzi, I'm leaving tomorrow. But I will be back soon. Maybe the next summer. (Said Larry through a phone call.) 
>   Uh, I see Larry.... 
>   2.1. I **look forward** to your return**ing**. 
>   2.2. I **am looking forward** to your return**ing**. 
>   2.3. I **am eagerly waiting** for your **return**. 
>   2.4. I **cannot wait** for your **return**.

To me they all mean the same and natural, however I need a native's confirmation on them.

PS. First of all, I am not quite confident whether the structures grammatically are correct.
Then, I am not sure if they are all natural sentences in English.

Please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: Corrections: .2. I eagerly wait Christmas every year.........................2.1. I look forward to you returning.
2.2. I am looking forward to your return.
2.3. I am eagerly awaiting for your return.
2.4. I cannot wait for your return.

Comment: Well, my 2.4. was exactly like your offered sentence @Bruce Murray. Meanwhile, is it correct to say: "2.1. I look forward to **you** returning" or that was a typo and should have been "your"?

Comment: I look forward to you returning.............generally demands something else:  I look forward to you returning on Monday. On the other hand, I look forward to your return..............can stand alone

Comment: @BruceMurray I would certainly say _wait for Christmas_ (or _await Christmas_). What variety of English do you speak? Also, your 2.3 should be _awaiting your return_.

Comment: I would accept OP's 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.3, and 2.4. In 2.1 and 2.2 I would use return instead of returning, as return is itself a noun, and the ing ending doesn't add anything except some awkwardness. You could however use ".. to you returning" in 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: Well @Peter do you mean "2.1. I look forward **to your return**" and "2.2. I am looking forward **to your return**"? Then may I ask you all my sentences in either set sound natural to you? Besides, it strikes me as if they are all formal and not suitable for casual speech. Do you agree?

Comment: In casual speech people would say _I can't wait for...._ It's a deliberate exaggeration (obviously you _have_ to wait, but you find it difficult), so not suitable for formal language. I can't imagine anyone actually saying _I cannot wait for..._ in real life.

Comment: Well @Kate Bunting what do you mean by "in real life"? What's wrong with "I can't wait for..."?

Comment: I didn't say that anything was wrong with 'I can't wait', I said that it was what most people would say. 'I _cannot_ wait' is unnatural because it combines the formal _cannot_ with an informal expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your sentences one by one.

> ```
> 1.1. I look forward to Christmas every year.
> ```

Correct. Can be formal or informal.

> ```
> 1.2. I eagerly wait for Christmas every year.
> ```

Correct. A little more formal.

> ```
> 1.3. I cannot wait for Christmas every year.
> ```

Correct, but slightly odd. It is an informal expression, so "can't" would probably be better than "cannot". Also "I can't wait" is usually about immediate feelings. I would use "I can't wait for Christmas this year" but probably not "I can't wait for Christmas every year." Others may disagree with me on this point.

> ```
> 2.1. I look forward to your returning.
> ```

This sentence uses "returning" as a noun, but "return" is itself a noun and in my opinion it is usually a better one to use. I would suggest "I look forward to your return."

> ```
> 2.2. I am looking forward to your returning.
> ```

The present continuous tense is a little bit odd as the response to Larry's announcement. I think sentence 2.1 "I look forward to your return" works better in this context, but I would prefer "I will look forward to your return" which talks about how Suzi will feel while Larry is away.

> ```
> 2.3. I am eagerly waiting for your return.
> ```

Correct, but rather formal. I have rarely heard "eagerly" used except when some formality
is intended. It also would work better as "I will eagerly wait for your return."

> ```
> 2.4. I cannot wait for your return.
> ```

In the context, "I can't wait for your return" is probably the best of the four. It is appropriately informal and suits the context well.